# SyntaxError Unexpected token 'export' (nuxt vue-echarts)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, echarts

#### Update - fixed, see my comment for link to resolution.

I am unable to work around the error "SyntaxError Unexpected token 'export'. I am using vue-echarts 6.0.0-beta.5 echarts 5.0.2, and nuxt 2.15.4. I have echarts v4 working fine within nuxt already and I'm trying to get echarts 5 working so I can upgrade since some features that are really nice.

If I am on a separate webpage already where I can navigate to this it works. If I do a page refresh or go to the page direct with a chart I get this error.

A working example of the problem can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bird-8eb1p). Alternately if going to an [invalid link](https://8eb1p.sse.codesandbox.io/invalid) and selecting the link to navigate to the home page the chart will come up until the page is refreshed.

Everything I can find on error states to make sure I have the following code in my nuxt.config.js which does not resolve the problem.

```
build: {
    transpile: ['vue-echarts']
  }
```

I am using the [vue-charts](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts) example.

```js
<template>
    <client-only>
        <v-chart class="chart" :option="option" />
    </client-only>
</template>

<script>
import { use } from "echarts/core";

import { CanvasRenderer } from "echarts/renderers";
import { PieChart } from "echarts/charts";
import {
    TitleComponent,
    TooltipComponent,
    LegendComponent,
} from "echarts/components";
import ECharts, { THEME_KEY } from "vue-echarts";

use([
    CanvasRenderer,
    PieChart,
    TitleComponent,
    TooltipComponent,
    LegendComponent,
]);

export default {
    components: { "v-chart": ECharts },
    provide: {
        [THEME_KEY]: "dark",
    },
    data() {
        return {
            option: {
                title: {
                    text: "Traffic Sources",
                    left: "center",
                },
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: "item",
                    formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)",
                },
                legend: {
                    orient: "vertical",
                    left: "left",
                    data: [
                        "Direct",
                        "Email",
                        "Ad Networks",
                        "Video Ads",
                        "Search Engines",
                    ],
                },
                series: [
                    {
                        name: "Traffic Sources",
                        type: "pie",
                        radius: "55%",
                        center: ["50%", "60%"],
                        data: [
                            { value: 335, name: "Direct" },
                            { value: 310, name: "Email" },
                            { value: 234, name: "Ad Networks" },
                            { value: 135, name: "Video Ads" },
                            { value: 1548, name: "Search Engines" },
                        ],
                        emphasis: {
                            itemStyle: {
                                shadowBlur: 10,
                                shadowOffsetX: 0,
                                shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.chart {
    height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I was able to get this resolved on GitHub. https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts/issues/536 updated codeply with working example https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-shirley-c6tfx?file=/nuxt.config.js.

Answer (score 4):

This helped me:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjs-vue-echarts-9jpl7?file=/components/Tutorial.vue

Specially this line in nuxt.config.js file:

```
  build: {
    transpile: [/echarts/, /zrender/]
  },
```

Comment: The transpile syntax has changed over time, and I expect will continue to change. Currently with echarts-gl added I have `transpile: ['claygl', 'echarts', 'zrender']`